# Display SQL Query result into a Django Form

Tags: python, html, sql-server, django

I have a simple BookStore web page that it must return a query result that contains books information.

I want to display that into a form and add checkbox before each item so the client can check the number of books they want.

First Question is how I pass an sql query into a django form (Form must be a Charfield with disable value set to true so no can edit it just be able to see it it also uses the widget textarea).
This is my Form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import Books


class Book_L(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is the Model.py the model i want to display is the Books model:

```
from django.db import models


class Books(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(db_column='UID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    bookname = models.CharField(db_column='BookName', max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    author = models.CharField(db_column='Author', max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    category = models.CharField(db_column='Category', max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qty = models.CharField(db_column='QTY', max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    price = models.CharField(db_column='Price', max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.


    

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Books'
```

This is my View.py the page that must display this result is the Homepage.html therefore the Homepage class:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from .models import Users,Books
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import Login_Form
from django import forms
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import *
from .forms import Book_L


def Homepage(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form =  Book_L(request)
    context ={}
    form = Book_L(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
  
  return render(request,'Homepage.html',{'form' : form})
```

and Finally my Homepage.html :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HomePage</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/MainWinIcon.ico">
        
    </head>
    <body style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:rgb(62,245,226);">
        <h1> Welcome to HomePage Select the Books you want and Press Submit </h1>
        
        <form  method="post">
            <fieldset>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                
            </fieldset>
            
        </form>
      
    

        <h2 style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:grey">Books List</h2>

       
        
    
    
    
    
    </body>




    
</html>
```

Mainly Im trying to display a Form that has a disabled text area with checkbox before each item;
The users will check the box they want and after they press submit a List of Selects Books (Their UID) must be returned for further processing (for example Added to another table called orders)

If it Helps I am using microsoft sql server 2019 and I edited the Settings file and connection between the database and django is OK and it normaly returns the results when I ask.

Comment: Please edit your question, remove unnecessary tags and not related to your issue code (CSS, view methods). Trim extra linebreaks.

Comment: Also please consider following recommended [naming convention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)

Comment: sorry now is it better? removed most of the code

Comment: still "god of line breaks needs more line breaks". hard to read. `If it Helps I am using microsoft sql server 2019` not really and there is zero TSQL lines of code, so no one following `sql-server` tag can help here.